# Entity Framework for ASP.NET Core MVC Music Store sample not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble with getting entity framework to work in general with my ASP.NET Core project so I decided to try and implement it using the sample music store project through this [github](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/dev/samples/MusicStore) link.

I have made sure that the directory package manager console is in is the root of the project where the project.json file resides "\samples\MusicStore".
I have also updated the connection string in the config.json file to a local database.

When I try to run any dotnet ef command I get the following error

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

I then tried installing the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package as I noticed it was not present in the project. I tried again, getting the same error.

I have made no other changes to the project.

Here is an image taken from CMD [image]

project.json file:

```
  {
  "authors": [
    "Microsoft"
  ],
  "description": "Music store application on ASP.NET 5",
  "version": "1.1.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [
        "Areas",
        "Views",
        "wwwroot",
        "config.json",
        "web.config",
        "ForTesting/**/*.json"
      ]
    },
    "define": [
      "DEMO"
    ],
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "warningsAsErrors": true
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "Areas",
      "Views",
      "wwwroot",
      "config.json",
      "web.config",
      "ForTesting/**/*.json"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-preview2-22516",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-22487",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "imports": "portable-net452+win81"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {},
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.1.0-*",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use the stable 1.0 branch of the music store application. http://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/1.0.0/ the dev branch requires ASP.NET Core 1.1 and its not released yet, so you'd need to add nightly nuget feed, but it may break often as new packages are partly deployed or versions missing for a certain .NET Core nightly build missing